# ajax javascript request not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, xmlhttprequest

I have this snippet below to fetch how score count on shared links on Reddit. Using Google Chrome I get a JSON response I can work with, but in Safari the same code sends me directly to "onerror" instead.

Help please :)

**UPDATE 1**

For some reason it doesn't work for me but for everyone else. I have all plugins disabled but can only get it to work in incognito mode.

**UPDATE 2**

It seems it affect some people using Safari, but not all. Safe to say, the fault must be in the browser and not in my code :)

```js
var myurl = 'http://www.google.com';    
var jsonURL = 'http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?url=' + myurl;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', jsonURL, true);

request.onload = function () {
  console.log('ON LOAD ------------------------------');
  var response = JSON.parse(request.response);
  console.log(response);
};
request.onerror = function () {
  console.log('ON ERROR ------------------------------');
  console.log(request);
};
request.send();
```

Comment: Works for me in Safari 9.1.1,  what version are you using ?

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Version 9.1.1 (11601.6.17).

Comment: That's weird, if I copy/paste my Safari version here's what I have : Version 9.1.1 (11601.6.17)
Any chance it might come from an authentication problem ?

Comment: Very weird. I just tried incognito mode. That works. But not in normal mode (all plugins disabled)

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I'm on Safari 9.1.1 OSX El Captain

Comment: @KarthickManoharan Do you have any browser plugins installed? If so, which?

Comment: @AndreasNorman Brand new machine. No plugins installed.

Comment: Weird. So the error only happen to some, like you and me?

Comment: My OS version is OS X EL Capitan 10.11.5, might come from it ? Would be weird, but maybe there's some OS plugins that you don't see as "normal" plugins ... worth to check, but would be really weird.